# Get records which are not ended with specific word

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, filter

I have field with values for instance:

```
323.12.444.1
55.1231
4543.432.431
6.1
456.3234.54353.1124.1
321.3.425
2.3.1
5345.43.1
432.5646.2
```

So for records ended by .1 has to be gathered. What should be the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be faster than `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE RIGHT(fieldname,2)='.1'
```

The `LIKE` with a `%` at the beginning is something one should avoid if possible...

Comment: I must admit: I did some tests and found that with an indexed column the `LIKE` is faster... Have to do some tests with this later... Without an index both approaches are quite the same...

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table where fieldname like '%.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col1),1,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(col1))-1)) = '1'
```

You can find any string you need without changing parameters inside query:

```
;WITH YourTable AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('323.12.444.1'),
('55.1231'),
('4543.432.431'),
('6.1'),
('456.3234.54353.1124.1'),
('321.3.425'),
('2.3.1'),
('5345.43.1'),
('432.5646.2')
) as t(col1)
)

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col1),1,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(col1))-1)) = '431'
```

Output:

```
4543.432.431
```